# Text too dense of half circles in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a small data set as follow:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1, 2), 3),
                 type = rep(c("A", "B"), 3),
                 country = rep(c("Japan", "Germany", "Korea"), each = 2),
                 count = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.2, 0.2, 3, 6))

df$country <- factor(df$country, levels = c("Japan", "Germany", "Korea"))
```

I have plotted half circles with code below:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=sqrt(count), fill=type)) + geom_col(width =1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", direction = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~country) +
  theme_void()+
  geom_text(aes(label=count), vjust=0, hjust = 0, size = 5)
```

Out:

[image]

As you can see, the geom text of Japan and Germany are too dense. So I wonder if there are a way to adjust the position of text without changing text's size.

I have tried by modifying the values of `vjust, hjust`, but it seems not working.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

By adding: `geom_text_repel(aes(label=value), vjust=0, hjust = 0, size = 2.5)`

Part of output of my real data:

[image]

By adding `geom_text(aes(label=value), size = 2.5, nudge_y = 0.5)`

Part of output of my real data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried different ways:

```
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=sqrt(count), fill=type)) + geom_col(width =1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", direction = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~country) +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=count), vjust=0, hjust = 0, size = 5)
```

[image]

Another way is to use `nudge_y` (I am not sure about the behavour of this method though):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=sqrt(count), fill=type)) + geom_col(width =1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", direction = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~country) +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(label=count), size = 5, 
            nudge_y = .5
  )
```

## Update:

If you adjust the overall size of the graph, you may get something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1, 2), 5),
                 type = rep(c("A", "B"), 5),
                 country = rep(c("Japan", "Germany", "Korea", "other1", "other2"), each = 2),
                 count = c(1208.734, 750.39, 1011.09, 444.83, 944.66, 295.68, 
                           698.17, 340.03, 
                           428.74, 430.15))

df$country <- factor(df$country, levels = c("Japan", "Germany", "Korea", "other1", "other2"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=sqrt(count), fill=type)) + geom_col(width =1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", direction = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~country, nrow =1) +
  theme_void()+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=count), 
                  vjust=0, 
                  hjust = 0, 
                  size = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works for large images when I set size of `2.5`, but not ideal for smaller ones yet, anyway to improve?  Please check my update part in question.

Comment: I see. I think it can be done by specifying a few things in `geom_text_repel`. I will try to revise the answer soon.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't lines for changing overall size of the graph in your code, I added `+ size(width=10, length=10)` in the end of my code, it didn't find this function.

Comment: Please try something like: `ggsave("newgraph.png", width=10, height=10)`

Comment: Thanks, sorry one more question, do you know how to increase the size of country names?

Comment: Try `+ theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16))`. You may want to get yourself familiar with `theme()` in `ggplot2` with a lot of options there.